# python Debugger: setting breakpoints, running

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I am trying to use the python debugger.

So far I have this in an interactive session:

```
    import observium.pollcd, pdb
    mypcd = observium.pollcd.PollCheckDaemon("observium/config.txt")
    pdb.run(mypcd.run)
```

And the REPL then shows:

```
    > /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py(23)enabled()
    -> import re
```

If I now list code ("l") I see code from this apport file. Why is this happening? What should I do so that I can instead see code from the PollCheckDaemon class? Thanks!

Comment: you can use "break" no?